# Batch CDC on Apache Seatunnel

Tags: mysql, change-data-capture

I have successfully installed Apache Seatunnal on my system. While executing the load data command on the source MySQL, which involves a CSV file containing 1 million records, I noticed that after the load execution is completed, there are 1 million individual insert operations being performed in Seatunnal to synchronize the data with the destination MySQL. I am interested in exploring the possibility of conducting batch insert operations in Seatunnal, such as inserting 100,000 records at a time or in similar increments, instead of individual inserts, in order to enhance efficiency.

Apache Seatunnal version: 2.3.1
MySQL version: 8.0.33

Is there a provision for batch inserts in the destination MySQL or CDC based on the last fetched ID ?

Here I Attach my conf file for CDC

```
env {
   job.mode = "STREAMING"
   parallelism = 2
}
source {
  MySQL-CDC {
    result_table_name="mysql-exactly-once"
    parallelism = 2
    server-id = 5656
    username = "hadoopuser"
    password = "Ambariuser.123"
    database-names = ["demo"]
    table-names = ["demo.source"]
    base-url = "jdbc:mysql://instance-3:3306/demo"
    startup.mode ="LATEST"
}
}
sink{
console
{
source_table_name="mysql-exactly-once"
}
jdbc {
        source_table_name="mysql-exactly-once"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://instance-4:3306/demo"
        driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        max_retries = 0
        user = "hadoopuser"
        password = "Ambariuser.123"
        query = "insert into dest(id,name) values(?,?)"
        is_exactly_once = "true"
        xa_data_source_class_name = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource"

}}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question with configuration file for CDC